# What is the difference between the configuration.files and configuration.copy methods in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

In Gradle User Guide [Chapter 23. Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) , an example show the difference between Configuration.copy and Configuration.files method :

```
build.gradle

task copyVsFiles << {
    configurations.sealife.copyRecursive { dep -> dep.name == 'orca' }
        .each { file -> println file.name }
    println()
    configurations.sealife.files { dep -> dep.name == 'orca' }
        .each { file -> println file.name }
}

Output of gradle -q copyVsFiles
> gradle -q copyVsFiles
orca-1.0.jar
seal-1.0.jar

orca-1.0.jar
seal-2.0.jar
```

the below explanation confused me. I still don't know the difference. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: There's an explanation right below the code snippet.  Can you clarify which part confuses you? (Otherwise you're just asking for someone to arbitrarily rephrase it for you!)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is an ELI5 question against the SO ethos?

Comment: @RaGe - yes, IMHO, given that the OP hasn't specified what's actually confusing, there's no way to answer this conclusively.

Comment: @ArronXY, can you update your question to explicitly ask, "What is the difference between the configuration.files and configuration.copy methods in Gradle?" Specifically highlight how you would like to understand the difference between how each method resolves dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the paragraph just after example 23.24 in the Gradle API documentation [Chapter 23 Section 24](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Note how the configurations.files method returns version 2 of the seal jar.

> In the example above, orca has a dependency on seal-1.0 whereas shark
>   has a dependency onseal-2.0. The original configuration has therefore
>   a version conflict which is resolved to the newer seal-2.0 version.
>   The files method therefore returns seal-2.0 as a transitive dependency
>   of orca. The copied configuration only has orca as a dependency and
>   therefore there is no version conflict and seal-1.0 is returned as a
>   transitive dependency.

To really understand why this happens spend some time looking at the Configuration method in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html).

Files does the following:

> Resolves this configuration. This locates and downloads the files
>   which make up this configuration. But only the resulting set of files
>   belonging to the subset of dependencies specified by the
>   dependencySpec is returned.

Copy does the following:

> Creates a copy of this configuration that only contains the
>   dependencies directly in this configuration (without contributions
>   from superconfigurations). The new configuration will be in the
>   UNRESOLVED state, but will retain all other attributes of this
>   configuration except superconfigurations. Configuration.getHierarchy()
>   for the copy will not include any superconfigurations.

How does this apply to the documentation example? `Configuration.files` resolves the configuration which, as shown by the output in the example, handles the version conflict introduced by `shark` which depends on `seal-2.0.jar`. `Configuration.copy` creates a copy of the configuration and is not yet resolved meaning it does not yet have a version conflict.

Comment: OP clearly states that they have seen this explanation and have trouble understanding it. No offence, but your answer doesn't do one bit to better that situation.